# Loading local JSON file with Safari Extension

Tags: xmlhttprequest, safari-extension

Trying to load JSON file with Safari Extension.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", safari.extension.baseURI +'js/data.json', true);
```

It gives an error "**Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.**"

For example it is possible with Chrome Extenison

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/js/data.json'), true);
```

There you need to specify it in manifest

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["/js/data.json"]
```

Is there a similar way in Safari?

**EDIT**
**Found a solution**

It is possible through Global page

*global.html*

```
function handleMessage(event) {
    if (event.name === "requestParagraphs") {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", safari.extension.baseURI + 'js/data.json', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                var articlesJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                event.target.page.dispatchMessage('paragraphs', articlesJSON);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

}
safari.application.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
```

*injected.js*

```
function handleMessage(msgEvent) {
        var messageName = msgEvent.name;
        var messageData = msgEvent.message;
        if (messageName === "paragraphs") {
           // ...
        }
}
    safari.self.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false); // Listen response
    safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('requestParagraphs'); // Call global page
```

Comment: Are you trying to load it in your global page's script? I thought it should work there.

Comment: Thx, through global page it worked :)